# AmCharts V4 (Maps) Zooming in Map creates scrollbar on both axis (IE only)

Tags: amcharts, ammap

I am using AmCharts (Maps) in Version 4. 
When zooming in a chart I get scrollbars (for x and y -axis).

Do I need to use some polyfills for IE?

Here is my current code: main.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Minimum Example</title>
  <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/maps.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/geodata/worldLow.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>

  <button id="us-button">Zoom to US</button>
  <br />
  <button id="br-button">Zoom to BR</button>
  <div id="chartdiv"></div>

  <script src="./main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

main.css

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Archivo+Narrow");

body {
  font-family: "Archivo Narrow";
}
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
}
```

main.js

```
/**
 * --------------------------------------------------------
 * This demo was created using amCharts V4 preview release.
 *
 * V4 is the latest installement in amCharts data viz
 * library family, to be released in the first half of
 * 2018.
 *
 * For more information and documentation visit:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/
 * --------------------------------------------------------
 */

/* Create map instance */
var chart = am4core.create('chartdiv', am4maps.MapChart);

/* Set map definition */
chart.geodata = am4geodata_worldLow;

/* Set projection */
chart.projection = new am4maps.projections.Miller();

/* Create map polygon series */
var polygonSeries = chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());

/* Make map load polygon (like country names) data from GeoJSON */
polygonSeries.useGeodata = true;

/* Configure series */
var polygonTemplate = polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template;
polygonTemplate.tooltipText = '{name}';
polygonTemplate.fill = am4core.color('#74B266');
polygonTemplate.events.on('hit', function(ev) {
  ev.target.series.chart.zoomToMapObject(ev.target);
});

/* Create hover state and set alternative fill color */
var hs = polygonTemplate.states.create('hover');
hs.properties.fill = am4core.color('#367B25');

// No thanks, Antarctica, no thanks.
polygonSeries.exclude = ['AQ'];

chart.zoomControl = new am4maps.ZoomControl();

var buttonTopPosition;

polygonSeries.events.on('inited', function() {
  polygonSeries.mapPolygons.each(function(polygon) {
    const id = polygon.dataItem.dataContext.id;
    let assignButton = false;

    switch (id) {
      case 'US':
        assignButton = 'us';
        break;

      case 'BR':
        assignButton = 'br';
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }

    if (assignButton) {
      const button = document.getElementById(assignButton + '-button');
      button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        chart = createMarkers(chart);
        setTimeout(function() {
          const animation = chart.zoomToMapObject(polygon);
        }, 500);
      });
    }
  });
});

function createMarkers(chart) {
  console.log('calling createMarkers');
  const demoAddress = { my_lat: 35.6895, my_lng: 139.6917 };
  const mapImageSeries = chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapImageSeries());

  const imageSeriesTemplate = mapImageSeries.mapImages.template;
  const circle = imageSeriesTemplate.createChild(am4core.Circle);
  circle.radius = 10;
  circle.fill = am4core.color('#ff0000');
  circle.stroke = am4core.color('#FFFFFF');
  circle.strokeWidth = 2;
  circle.nonScaling = true;
  circle.tooltipText = 'hi';
  imageSeriesTemplate.propertyFields.latitude = 'latitude';
  imageSeriesTemplate.propertyFields.longitude = 'longitude';
  mapImageSeries.data = { latitude: demoAddress.latitude, longitude: demoAddress.longitude };
  return chart;
}
```

To replicate my issue use Internet Explorer 11 and open index.html
then zoom into a country and see how the scrollbars increase with zoom level.

Comment: FYI, you don't need to add a polyfill if you're using the files on the amcharts.com domain as they are already included. Polyfills are only needed if you're grabbing the amcharts files from npm. That said, it looks like a bug to me and I'm reaching out to the team to confirm.

Comment: Bug confirmed. If you want to subscribe to the issue on github, [here is the link](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/issues/411). As a temporary workaround, add `overflow: hidden;` to your chart div.